# Where can I find a scroll bar plugin like facebook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, scrollbar

I am looking for a Scrollbar plugin(js, jquery etc.) like they show on Facebook's Top right panel for latest live streams of our Friends. Where can I find it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've successfully used the jQuery plugin [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) before.

You would need to make your own style to emulate the Facebook slider.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a scrollbar plugin. just CSS, JavaScript & HTML . If you are interested, you can look into Facebook's codes & stylesheets to learn what's going on.

Comment: A plugin _is_ made up of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. :)

Answer (score 1):

a jquery plugin

http://jsfiddle.net/PVZB8/1559/

Answer (score 0):

To your delight there are a few plugins out there but I use JScrollPane.

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/#examples